# Java Swing Timer how to use it

Tags: java, swing, timer

I basecally want it to press "Space" to start the timer then stop it after a certain Y cordinate point and then start again when "Space" key is pressed if that makes sence. curently it isnt really working its just stopping completely and not "Purging" so im kinda lost rn. if any of you have a idea about this please share!!

iv been thinking and i probably need a String for my timer which i never done before so any help or a link to an article would be helpful

here's what iv done so far.

```
if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
    long počasi=10;
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            y1 = y1 - 1;
            jButton2.setLocation(x1, y1);
            if (y1 < 0) {
                timer.cancel();
                jButton2.setLocation(x, y);
                timer.purge();
            }
        }
    }, new Date(), počasi);
}
```

Comment: Your question is missing a question currently. What do you need help with?

Comment: Oh my bad so um, i curently dont know how to make this work so, i basecally want it to press "Space" to start the timer then stop it after a certain Y cordinate point and then start again when "Space" key is pressed if that makes sence. iv been thinking and i probably need a String for my timer which i never done before so any help or a link to an article would be helpfull.

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50735166/edit) your question with the additional information :)

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand what a string is, but I don't see the relation with a timer in any way.  The only thing I can make from this is that you want your slidding button to start over when you press space, and for that, the only thing that is missing is resetting `y1` to some initial value.

Comment: [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First start by having a look at [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for details about how to use Swing `Timer` and why you should.

Next, in your class, create a `timer` property...

```
private Timer timer;
```

Then in your constructor, create an instance of the `Timer`...

```
timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        y1 = y1 - 1;
        if (y1 < 0) {
            y1 = 0;
            timer.stop();
        }
        jButton2.setLocation(x1, y1);
    }
});
```

Then, when you need to, start the `timer`...

```
if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
        long počasi=10;
        if (!timer.isRunning()) {
            timer.start();
        }
}
```

Next, go read [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which will solve all the issues with `KeyListener`, especially if you have other controls which can obtain keyboard focus

Also, remember, component animation is difficult. If your container has a layout manager, you will be fighting it